# Subclassing a decorated JavaScript Class

Tags: javascript, babeljs, ecmascript-2016

I'm decorating a class to provide arguments to it's constructor, the problem arises when I try to subclass this class:

```
@decorate('foo', 'bar')
class Foo {
    constructor(foo, bar) {}
}

class Bar extends Foo {}


function decorate(foo, bar) {
    return function(ctor) {
        return ctor.bind(null, foo, bar);
    };
}
```

The above won't work because of the `null` context passed to the constructor (at least I think that is the root of the issue). When used with Babel, this is the following error: " Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined"

Is there any way to both decorate the parent class and extend the child?

Comment: I think it's more about not supplying `new` there. If your `function(ctor)` looks like `return function() { return new ctor(foo, bar); }`, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to extend a function that has been created via `.bind` is not going to work for you. Bound functions have tons of special logic around them. Bound functions do not have a `.prototype` property, which means extending a bound function would mean there was no prototype chain to follow. The proper way to implement this decorator would be to do

```
function decorate(foo, bar) {
  return ctor => class extends ctor {
    constructor(...args){
      super(foo, bar, ...args);
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: It's not so much the special logic I'd say, the error hints at their lack of a `.prototype` property.